# WPF - Observable Collection new record from xml binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a page with tabcontrol.

I am binding a list of locations a tabitem in the control.

The records are listed in a listview.

I am able to edit records by binding input controls to the listview.selecteditem.

My problem is when I want to add a new record. I want to minimise code behind.

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> _locations;

    public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
    }

    public LocationListViewModel()
    {
        _locations = new ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>();

        foreach (Service.Location l in service.GetLocationList().OrderBy(l => l.Building).ThenBy(l => l.Floor))
        {
            _locations.Add(new LocationViewModel
                                {
                                    id = l.id,
                                    Building = l.Building,
                                    Floor = l.Floor,
                                    RoomNo = l.RoomNo,
                                    MapTitle = l.MapTitle,
                                    MapExtension = l.MapExtension,
                                    Map = l.Map,
                                    DateCreated = l.DateCreated,
                                    CreatedByID = l.CreatedByID,
                                    CreatedByDesc = l.CreatedByDesc,
                                    DateEdited = l.DateEdited,
                                    EditedByID = l.EditedByID,
                                    EditedByDesc = l.EditedByDesc
                                }
                            );
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabSettingsLocations" x:Uid="tabSettingsLocations" 
    Header="Locations"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LocationList}"> .....
```

Example of successful binding to listview for edits

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSettingLocationBuildingEdit" 
    Margin="90,17,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SettingsTextBoxStyle}"
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Building, ElementName=lvwSettingsLocations,
    Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Example of unsuccessful binding for new record (uses different set of input controls)

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSettingLocationBuildingAdd"  
    Margin="90,17,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SettingsTextBoxStyle}" 
    Text="{Binding Building, ElementName=lvwSettingsLocations, 
    Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

I also tried to bind the child tab item to the same data source

```
<TabItem x:Name="tbSettingsLocationsAdd" x:Uid="tbSettingsLocationsAdd" 
    Header="Add New"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LocationList}">

<TextBox x:Name="txtSettingLocationBuildingAdd"  
    Margin="90,17,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SettingsTextBoxStyle}" 
    Text="{Binding Building}"/>
```

To no avail.

I also tried creating a new child dataview but I want it all to be bound together so that the interface updates whatever I do add or edit.

Anyone help?

Comment: did you set the dataContext?

Comment: It is not really clear what the problem is, you are talking about succesfull and unsuccesfull binding, yet you state that you want to minimize code-behind for the 'add' method. At least you shouldn't be doing this `Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Building, ElementName=lvwSettingsLocations,
    Mode=TwoWay}"` but add the following to the `TextBox`. `DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lvwSettingsLocations}" Text="{Binding Path=Building}"` Binding works well on properties, not on 'subproperties', at least very poorly for properties of properties in that way.

Comment: I have taken your advice and restructured my bindings. It does not however cure the new entry problem. The problem is that the new Location viewmodel does not exist. It appears that I will need to make the add in the code behind using observablecollection.add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I nailed this in the end. Just wanted to share ... thanks to Silvermind for a good tip on best practice.

Command:

```
class Location_Add : ICommand
{
    private ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> _llvm;

    public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> llvm
    {
        get { return _llvm; }
    }

    public Location_Add(ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> passedllvm)
    {
        _llvm = passedllvm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        LocationViewModel lvw = parameter as LocationViewModel;
        return lvw != null;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
            LocationViewModel lvm = parameter as LocationViewModel;
            llvm.Add(lvm);
            AddLocation(lvm);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void AddLocation(LocationViewModel lvm)
    {
        try
        {
            Service.SchoolMonitorServiceClient service = new Service.SchoolMonitorServiceClient();

            Service.Location loc = new Service.Location();
            loc.Building = lvm.Building.Trim();
            loc.Floor = lvm.Floor.Trim();
            loc.RoomNo = lvm.RoomNo.Trim();
            loc.MapTitle = lvm.MapTitle;
            loc.MapExtension = lvm.MapTitle.Substring(lvm.MapTitle.IndexOf("."));
            loc.Map = lvm.Map;
            loc.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            loc.CreatedByID = (Int32)Application.Current.Resources["UserID"];
            loc.DateEdited = lvm.DateEdited;

            service.AddLocation(loc);
            MessageBox.Show("Your new Location was entered successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class LocationListViewModel
{
    Service.SchoolMonitorServiceClient service = new Service.SchoolMonitorServiceClient();

    #region Members

    private ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> _locations;
    private Location_Add _AddCommand;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
    }

    #endregion

    public LocationListViewModel()
    {
        _locations = new ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>();

        foreach (Service.Location l 
            in service.GetLocationList()
            .OrderBy(l => l.Building).ThenBy(l => l.Floor))
        {
            _locations.Add(new LocationViewModel
                                {
                                    id = l.id,
                                    Building = l.Building,
                                    Floor = l.Floor,
                                    RoomNo = l.RoomNo,
                                    MapTitle = l.MapTitle,
                                    MapExtension = l.MapExtension,
                                    Map = l.Map,
                                    DateCreated = l.DateCreated,
                                    CreatedByID = l.CreatedByID,
                                    CreatedByDesc = l.CreatedByDesc,
                                    DateEdited = l.DateEdited,
                                    EditedByID = l.EditedByID,
                                    EditedByDesc = l.EditedByDesc
                                }
                            );
        }

        _AddCommand = new Location_Add(_locations);
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _AddCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SchoolMonitor_WPF.ViewModels"

<Page.Resources>
    <local:LocationListViewModel x:Key="LocationList" />
    <local:LocationViewModel x:Key="NewLocation" />
</Page.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="txtSettingLocationBuildingAdd" x:Uid="txtSettingLocationBuildingAdd"  
    Margin="90,17,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SettingsTextBoxStyle}"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewLocation}"
    Text="{Binding Path=Building}"/>

<Button x:Name="btnSettingsLocationSaveAdd" Content="Submit" Margin="0,80,10,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LocationList}"
    CommandParameter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewLocation}" 
    Command="{Binding AddCommand}">
```

Hope this helps someone.